# Which is better CMD or Cygwin for a invoking cl.exe in windows?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, cmd, cygwin, cl

I want to compile some C programs in windows by Visual Studio.

What should I use to invoke cl.exe, Cygwin or cmd.exe?

Comment: Which version of visual studio do you have ? Why  won't you use visual studio for compiling c programs ?

Comment: Either will work. What you choose depends on the other tools you use for development.

Comment: I want to compile from command line, bot by IDE.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Hi R Sahu..
My question is, which is better?
If in future some changes happened in Windows then which approach will not be affected?

Comment: Change can happen at any front that is being considered. Go ahead with the current approach based on your present development requirement/setup.